# Protractor - How to use async/await

Tags: javascript, protractor, jasmine, nodejs

I am completely new to protractor, and I came across the **async/await**.

Using:

- node version 8.9.4
- protractor version 5.3.0.
  Is it necessary to use async/await in all your script? And how to use with page object.

Here's the code I tried

**test1.js**

```js
    describe("first protractor test",function(){
    var originalTimeout;
    async beforeEach(function(){
         await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false); //false to remove error for angular page not found
         await browser.get("https://54.75.182.9/ems",5000);     //34.22.196.20 another url
         originalTimeout = jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL;
         jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 10000;
    
    });
    
    afterEach(function(){
    jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = originalTimeout;
    });
    
    var home_page=require('./home_page.js');
    it("first test- login test",function(){
            home_page.enterUser();
            home_page.enterPwd();
            
            var transact=home_page.clickLoginfunction();  // that ref is used here
            transact.clickReport();
            transact.clickTransact();
            transact.selectOption();
            transact.clickSearch();
            transact.clickViewDetails();
            transact.getNGtext();
    });
});
```

**transact.js**

```js
     var transact_page= function(){
    
    //browser.pause();
    
    this.clickReport=function(){
    await  element(by.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Reports')]")).click();
    };
    
    this.clickTransact=function(){
        await element(by.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Transaction History')]")).click();
    };
    
    this.selectOption=function(){
        await element(by.model("searchTypeEntity")).$('[value="Contact"]').click();
    };

    this.clickSearch=function(){
        await element(by.id("searchTransBtn")).click();
    };
    
    this.clickViewDetails=function(){
        await element(by.xpath("//a[contains(.,'View Details')]")).click();
    };
    
    this.getNGtext=function(){
        return await element(by.model("val")).getText();
        
    
    };
    
    };  
    module.exports=new transact_page();




      **homepage.js** 
      require('./transact.js');  // mentioning beforehand
      var home_page=function(){
    
    this.enterUser=function(){
        await element(by.id("username")).sendKeys("admin");
    };

    this.enterPwd=function(){
        await element(by.id("password")).sendKeys("admin");
    };
    
    this.clickLoginfunction=function(){
        await element(by.id("login")).click();
        await browser.driver.sleep(10000);
        return require('./transact.js');  // this will return a ref to that particular page
    };
    
    };
      module.exports=new home_page // need this so that its object can be used in other classes eg. main
```

Answer (score 4):

### Where to use async-await in Protractor scripts?

Async/await statements are only required in places where promise resolution is occurring before moving to the next statement so yes, it is only required for asynchronous promise returning statements.

### Why use async-await in Protractor scripts?

WebDriverJS (and thus, Protractor) APIs are entirely asynchronous. All functions return promises., which are managed by a [control flow](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs#control-flows).

**Disabling the Control Flow**

In the future, the control flow is being removed.
Instead of the control flow, we can synchronize the selenium commands with [promise chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) or  ES7 feature [async-await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

The latest Node.js provides native async/await, which means we can get the stable e2e test without using control flow in a javascript test.

Note: To write and run native async/await test, the node.js version should be greater than or equal to 8.0, and Jasmine version should be greater than or equal to 2.7.

### **Async-Await in Page Objects:**

The page object is just a design pattern to better structure automation  whereas async await is a waiting mechanism for promises to be resolved  and make javaScript code appear more synchronous without using '.then'.

**Code in Page object before Async-Await**

```
 clickOnSelectCustomer: function () {
   browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(customersTextBox), Medium_Wait()).then(function () {
      actions.Click(customersTextBox, 'Clicking on Customer Name Textbox')
    })
  },
```

**Code in Page object after Async-Await**

```
    async clickOnSelectCustomer () {
     await browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(customersTextBox), Medium_Wait())
     actions.Click(customersTextBox, 'Clicking on Customer Name Textbox')
   },
```

### Simpler Error-Handling

If a promise resolves normally, then await promise returns the result. But in case of a rejection, it throws the error, just if there were a throw statement at that line.

In real situations, the promise may take some time before it rejects. So await will wait, and then throw an error.

We can catch that error using try..catch, the same way as a regular throw:

```
async function f() {

  try {
    let response = await fetch('http://no-such-url');
  } catch(err) {
    alert(err); // TypeError: failed to fetch
  }
}

f();
```

Without using '.then' and nested code,async-await make the code more *linear* which is easier to understand and write which in turn makes it easier to maintain as well.

[Protractor Official Documentation On Async/Await](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/async-await.md)

Comment: Thanks for clearing some doubts but what i read aync/await is used for asynchronous coding which was prevalent in js in promises and callback(prev versions). So is it really necessary to code whole script in async/await or just to use when asynchronous code is required?
Also I tried the code using async/await but failed , getting error that it is rejected.

Comment: If you have any further specific code issues, please post as a separate question.

Comment: As I mentioned async-await is for the asynchronous code returning promises only.I also added links so you may read further.

Comment: Please like the answer if it helped you.